# Generating Variables' Names

Tags: c++, variables

I want to generate some variables using for command. look at code below:

```
for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++)
      int ch=0;
```

It just an example, after running code above, I want to have int a, int b, int c ...

another example:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      int NewiEnd=0;
```

For example after running code above, we will have int New1End, int New2End etc.

Hope I'm clear enough, How can I do such thing in C++??

Comment: No. Why would you need this? There are containers.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement that the numeric values from `a` to `z` represent the letters a-z and nothing else. For example, in the EBCDIC encoding, there's quite a bit of punctuation stuck in the middle of that range of character codes.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I was in the middle of typing that :p

Comment: I think EBCDIC can be safely ignored by most people.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I wish I could ignore it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not possible, not exactly.  However, this is possible:

```
std::map<char,int> vars;    
for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++)
      vars[ch] = 0;

std::cout << vars['a'] << vars['b'] << vars['c'];
```

You can also have `std::map<std::string, int>`.

```
std::map<std::string,int> vars;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    vars["New" + std::to_string(i) + "End"] = 0;
std::cout << vars["New5End"];
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but Which header should I use for using map command?

Comment: @Stranger: `<map>` -- And it's not a command, it's a class template. [Here's some unofficial documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: What should I write If I want to use map? I have written the code above but it is not working, should I add the whole class template of map into my source code?

Comment: @Stranger Just put `#include <map>`. If this doesn't work, show us your error.

Comment: Ok, I have tested it and it is working now, but it is not what really I'm looking for, because I must use Name["TargetItem"] for reaching my variable, for example I need Varsa not Vars['a']. So is there any way to fix it too?

Comment: @Stranger: No, that is absolutely not possible with C++, as we have been telling you.  If you need that so bad, then you are using the wrong language.  Try python, where it is possible.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley "...you keep using that word.  I don't think it mean what you think it mean."  :)  ["impossible"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221189/211160)

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do isn't possible in C or C++.

Comment: So What should I do? I need to do such thing, I believe nothing is impossible :)

Comment: @Stranger Those are what arrays are for.

Comment: @Stranger: Count to infinity and then we talk again about `nothing is impossible` :)

Comment: @David just think I want to generate David1Stranger, David2Stranger etc, How can I enter numbers between them? I believe it is not a good way doing it by hands ;)

Comment: @Stranger: It seems you are trying to solve a problem and present only part of it to us. Maybe we could help you better when you present your whole problem and the part of your solution you are stuck with.

Comment: @Nobody - counting to infinity is a well-known problem for internet router protocols, and it's solved by defining infinity as a small finite value.

Comment: @PeterBecker: Well then let me define that I am right :) It was just an example to show that there _are_ things that are impossible.

Comment: Mathematicians count to infinity all the time.  In fact, they know the [relative size of infinities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) and can tell you when one is bigger or smaller than another.  Also, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221189/211160).

Comment: @HostileFork: There seems to be a misunderstanding of counting. I do not know of anyone (except Chuck Norris) who was able to count to infinity. Of course it is possible to work with infinity as mathematicians do but they do not count to infinity one by one.

Comment: @Nobody you didn't say "one by one", although that in itself would have to be formally defined before being called impossible within said formalism...

Comment: @HostileFork: Lets end this here I think the purpose of my initial comment was clear. I surrender to the mathematical correctness :) Just in case you were getting this wrong: My initial comment was never intended to sound that harsh like it does in retrospective. I just wanted to give a short example that showed the limitations we all have to face. Now I see I had better chosen an example that was closer to the problem like: You cannot name a variable `*` or so. So once again sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

What you seem to want is a map of the type:

```
std::map<std::string, int> ints;
```

This will let you call "variables" by name:

```
ints["a"] = 0;
ints["myVariable"] = 10;
```

Or as given in your example:

```
std::map<char, int> ints;
for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++)
   ints[ch] = 0;
```

If you are just about to use 'a' - 'z' you could use an array of ints:

```
int ints['z' + 1];
ints['a'] = 0;
ints['z'] = 0;
```

But this allocates unnecessary space for the ascii characters below 'a'.

Comment: As well as unnecessary space in the middle for some encodings. Not all the world is ASCII.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I never though about it but is there no line in the standard that says: convert char literals like 'a' to integers using ASCII?

Comment: There's one specific requirement about encodings for characters: the code points for `'0'` through `'9'` must be contiguous and increasing, so that you can say `ch - '0'` to get the value of a character that represents one of those digits.

Comment: Character constants are just integral constants. `'a'` is a number, just as `97` is a number. Its value is determined by the encoding (ASCII, EBCDIC, whatever) of the source character set.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ the variable names have "gone away" by the time the code has been compiled and run.  You can't print out the name of an existing variable at run time via "reflection"...much less make new named variables.  People looking for this feature find out that the only generalized way you can do it falls down to using the preprocessor:

[generic way to print out variable name in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622962/generic-way-to-print-out-variable-name-in-c)

The preprocessor could *theoretically* be applied to your problem as well, with certain constraints:

[Writing a while loop in the C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor)

But anyone reading your code would probably drive a stake through your heart, and be justified in doing so.  Both Sunday-morning laziness and a strong belief that it's not what you (should) want leads me to not try and write a working example.  :-)

*(For the curious, the preprocessor is not Turing-Complete, although there are some ["interesting" experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136686/is-the-c99-preprocessor-turing-complete))*

The nature of C/C++ is to have you build up named tables on an as-needed basis.  The languages that offer this feature by default make you pay for the runtime tracking of names whether you wind up using reflection or not, and that's not in the spirit of this particular compiled language.  Others have given you answers that are more on the right track.