# Is it possible to create variables during runtime in c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a new variable for a function everytime the function is called? I was considering making a huge array and just using a different block for each time a function is called but I would prefer to create variables on demand instead, is this possible in c++?

Example:
A user types asdf and clicks save, setting off the savetext function

```
void savetext(textvariable)
{
static int //(this variable name should somehow become asdf) = somedata;
return;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like dynamic allocation (using `new`) is the answer, but could you give an example of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: huge array = use a `std::vector<>`; outside of that, not really sure where you're going with the whole "create variables" approach.

Comment: Variable values are not "remembered" for the next call of the function anyway, unless they are `static`.

Comment: Do you mean new block for the function? Seems to me you would like to construct an array of pointers to functions. Please give a more detailed example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm still mostly in the process of learning programming although a specific desired use prompted me to ask this question I don't want to include it because there are multiple other solutions and I wanted to know the answer to this for future references as well, not just solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Honestly your question doesn't make sense... I think the closest thing to what you're asking for is delayed initialization.

Comment: Variables are exclusively a compile-time concept. As such you cannot _create_ variables at run-time. I'm having a feeling that the question you asked is not what you meant to ask. Consider rephrasing your question using appropriate terminology.

Comment: Now, after your edit, it sounds like it's a duplicate of one of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220957/generating-variables-names

Comment: Maybe what you need is `std::map<std::string, DataType>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something that, for example, adds things to an array, then `vector` is the right solution. The `vector` class will automatically grow as you need it, using the `push_back` function to add things to itself.

The vector class acts largely as an array that grows as you need it to, so it's very easy to use.

Comment: No, the default for "I need to store a bunch of stuff" is vector. Only when you have shown somehow that vector isn't good enough (either can't do what you want, or some performance reason) should you use other things.

Comment: `std::vector<>` is the right solution if, and **only** if, you are required to have the controlled sequence be in contiguous memory. More often than not when people recommend `std::vector<>` they actually meant `std::deque<>`.

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for, I'll look into this, thankyou.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use a std::vector<std::string> if you want to save a bunch of text. Let each entry be a line of text, or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you enter a function, all variables in it are new. There's no need to explicitly create variables unless you need objects that live longer than your function, or you don't know how many you need.

Comment: That's part of what I was implying, that the variables would basically now act similar to global variables in that they would outlive my function, but I'm not sure static would solve the problem unless I can make a dynamic name for the variable each time it's called.