# Is there a way to display/print the attribute of variable/member in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on someone else project in C++. There are many variables which are created based on other classes. For example:

`Class_C newVariable;`

which `Class_C` is created based on `Class_B` and may be inherit from `Class_A` and so on, thus `newVariable` may contain many class members.

Is there anyway or easy to print or display all members of `newVariable` in C++?

> ps. I am using Visual Studio for coding and debugging.

Comment: No, that would require reflection. The most you can currently get is the class name. Something like intellisense in Visual Studio is what would help you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently asked myself the same question. Take a look at the following discussions:

[how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

[generic-way-to-print-out-variable-name-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622962/generic-way-to-print-out-variable-name-in-c)

[Meta Classes](http://www.vollmann.com/en/pubs/meta/meta/meta.html)

["Reflection" Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0114hz2.aspx)

To sum it up, C++ is built for speed, there is no way to get the info about your classes (during the runtime), at least not using a core feature of C++ (as we have reflection in Java). There are different tricks and extensions to do that (as you can find in the links posted above), but they are still... tricks and extensions.