# how can I use a function to print the name of args not use define In c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define debug(x) cout<<#x<<": "<<(x)<<endl;

int main() {

    int a = 0;
    debug(a)
    return 0;
}
```

***the output is:*** **a:0** 
I want to print the name of variable like a

can I do it by a function not use `define`

Comment: No. Functions have no information about how their arguments were constructed.

Comment: "Stringification" with `#` is a preprocessor macro-only thing. You can create a macro to *call* a function, passing e.g. `#x` as argument, but you can't use the operator in plain C++ code.

Comment: You will regrettably need a macro. The name of a variable is lost at runtime so something must be done at compile time.

Comment: Are you willing to build with debug information?  And then use that debug information to reflect upon the string of the name associated with a variable?  It will be extraordinarily slow, but it will work, and won't be portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the answers here can help you :
[generic way to print out variable name in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622962/generic-way-to-print-out-variable-name-in-c)
and it seems the only way is using macro!

Comment: Please take some time to read or refresh [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Link-only answers like your are generally discouraged. And with a link to Stack Overflow itself it's better to vote to close as a duplicate instead.